# HttpURLConnection POST parameters does not work correctly

Tags: android, https, http-post

I created HttpURLConnection with POST request and parameters to send to the server. The server response with:

> Integrity constraint violation: Column 'operator_id' cannot be null

But I clearly sent it in the query. I tried using curl via terminal and it works fine. The server accepts the query and save it to the db. I match all the value of parameters in the curl and the Android call but it is no help.

Here is the AsyncTask class.

```
public class HttpPost extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
  Context context;
  public HttpPost (Context context){
    this.context = context;
  }
   @Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    URL url;
    String response = "";
    try {
            url = new URL(params[0]);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            String query = "operator_id=1&date=*********";
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(query);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();

            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            .......
            conn.disconnect();
    catch ( Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return response;
}
```

Here is the curl call

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"operator_id":1,"date":"",other value...}'  https://www.mywebsite.com/
```

Anyone has any idea what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to wrap the string params in valid JSON should work.

```
String query = "{\"operator_id\":1,\"date\":\"*********\"}";
```

Comment: Oh god. I thought query is to append to the url. It is working now. Thanks.

Comment: It was a bit curious since you did it right in the curl call!